# Deploy kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war on wildfly-8.1.0.Final

Tags: drools, wildfly, drools-guvnor, wildfly-8, kie

I deployed successfully kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, running with jdk1.7.0_10.

But this configuration ...

- kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war
- wildfly-8.1.0.Final
- jdk1.7.0_10

.. fails to deploy with this error :

```
    14:58:06,531 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016011: Warning while parsing vfs:/C:/java/too
ls/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-guvnor/bin/content/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml:
1 cvc-elt.1 : DÚclaration de l'ÚlÚment 'beans' introuvable.
14:58:07,500 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module
.service."deployment.kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartExcep
tion in service jboss.module.service."deployment.kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war".main: JBAS
018759: Failed to load module: deployment.kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-jboss-as7.0.war:main
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Fi
nal.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-ms
c-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.F
inal.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_10]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty:main
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1406) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1434) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Fi
nal.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
```

The drools-wb documentation here : 
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html#wb.Installation

> jboss-as7: tailored for JBoss AS 7 (which is being renamed to WildFly
>   in version 8)

So the doc, let me think that this 6.0.1.Final release of the workbench should work well with wildfly. I might be wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to figured out.

Thanks to this blog entry : 
https://mswiderski.blogspot.ch/2014/06/lets-wildfly-with-jbpm6.html

So, obviously a kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-**jboss-as7.0**.war cannot be deployed to wildfly. But the documentation was confused.

Starting from version 6.1.0, there is a kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.1.0.CR1-**wildfly**.war - I found it here : 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars/6.1.0.CR1/

Finally, wildfly can be started with the default standalone.xml profile 
*(the standalone-full.xml profile is required for the kie-wb)*

Hope that will be helpful for someone.